# Android - Suggest a proper way to alert a user for an important notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

So, I'm building a Ride Hailing app and I'm still not sure of what route should I go with for alerting a user for a New Ride Reuest.

- Should I go with Draw Over Other Apps to open the activity when the notification is received.
- Should I use fullScreenNotificationIntent with showOnLockScreen

And if I use fullScreenNotificationIntent, the Android system not always open the activity, it shows a headsupNotification, and I will have to add and handle accept reject actions.

Need a proper professional suggestion on this.

Comment: The second one.  Draw over other apps and forcing your Activity open is extremely disruptive.  You just need the user to see it.  Even something as urgent as a phone call doesn't kick you out of what you're doing.

Comment: @RyanM
Understandable, and also, Draw over is apparently up to be deprecated.

But, what approach should I go with in showing a full screen intent, should I show buttons on the notification itself for when the system decides to show a heads-up notification instead of launching the intent, also, for alert, should I use a seperate service to run a soundpool and vibrator, so it can get noticed if the driver is in someother call etc

Comment: That part is somewhat further outside my area of expertise - I'm not sure of the details, sorry.